# Leadwerks project import to Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

im trying to make my first 3D oriented game, using Leadwerks i have created some 3D enviroment, but after importing project to visual studio 2015 it seems that ''Leadwerks.h'' is missing, where can i find this header file and how to propely configure project?

im following this tutorial:

http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/building-a-first-person-shooter-part-11-visual-studio-setup-r3099

Comment: Did you download and install the 30 trial ( or a paid license) of the leadwerks software?

Comment: its 14 days trial from steam